# Crear grupos de datos con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ciencia-de-datos

Estoy practicando con Pandas y necesito hacer grupos de datos por una condición. En la solapa "origin" tengo el dataset inicial y en la "sheet2", es el resultado que tengo que obtener. ¿ Alguien que tenga practica en Python y Pandas que me pueda ayudar ?

[dataset y resultado final](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SaScXv3fAiwWaHo4A9ICYdmpyznC2BlByri1PEPwxA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

te invito a que lo pruebes primero. Y luego después de las dudas que tengas, preguntarnos. Y así poder ver posibles errores. Aún así te doy una posible solución para que te inicies en pandas. He supuesto que lees un excel, por eso hago uso de read_excel, ya que he creado un excel con los datos del que es tu dataset.

Por partes. He creado un método que te compara la columna "1er tramo" fila por fila para  ver si hay cambios. Al tener datos en el resto de columnas, he evitado hacer un groupby(), y como estás empezando, por lo menos ve que se descompone en Series y se puede iterar.

```
df = pd.read_excel("TestStackOverFlow.xlsx", index_col=False)

def prueba(df):

    lista = df["1er tramo"]
    p = []
    indice = []
    variable = 1
    variable_indice = 1
    for index, x in enumerate(lista.values):
        if index == 0:
            p.append(variable)
            indice.append(variable_indice)
        else:
            if x == lista.values[index-1]:
                variable = variable + 1
                p.append(variable)
                indice.append(variable_indice)
            else:
                variable = 1
                variable_indice = variable_indice + 1
                p.append(variable)
                indice.append(variable_indice)
    df["orden"] = pd.DataFrame(p, columns=["orden"])
    df["new_range"] = pd.DataFrame(indice, columns=["new_range"])
    aux.drop(columns=["p"])
    return df

aux = prueba(df)
```

En la solución la función prueba te devuelve un nuevo df. con las columnas que necesitas y el orden y nuevo rango.

PD: He pasado una posible solución para que empieces a probar a hacerlo tú. Pero no es la norma. A programar se aprende intentándolo y leyendo mucha documentación. Aquí tienes [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) de pandas

Comment: Pedroja, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y la explicación. Ahora lo pruebo y voy entendiendo lo que hiciste. Estoy practicando pero me quede atascado en esa parte, espero poder seguir avanzando después de tu ayuda. Muchas gracias

Comment: @diego prueba el código y verifica si es lo que deseas, por el ejemplo que vi en tu spreadsheet si hace lo que quieres. Hay más opciones. Pandas tiene mucho fondo y puedes aprender mucho, espero te sirva este ejemplo.